# Logging framework for Windows Store Apps

Tags: logging, windows-store-apps

I'm looking to build logging and instrumentation into my windows store app, any recommendation around good logging frameworks for windows store apps?
I know I can roll my own by writing to a file or Azure Storage, was curious if there is anything out there already

Answer (score 1):

Go for [MetroLog](https://github.com/mbrit/metrolog).

> MetroLog is a lightweight logging framework designed for Windows Store
>   and Windows Phone 8 apps. Although the API is based on NLog and
>   log4net, the intention is that it's a very basic logging system.

Answer (score 1):

You also can take a look at [MarkedUp](https://markedup.com/) which provides both logging and analytics features. Usually it takes about 1 hour to see updated data on your dashboard there.

Update: [MarkedUp is no longer working after Nov 30th, 2014](http://blog.markedup.com/2014/11/markedup-is-shutting-down/)

Comment: MarkedUp is now finished.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **[Google Analytics SDK for Windows 8 and Windows Phone](http://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/)**

You can use it with **Javascript** and **C#/XAML** apps and get the common features that Google analytics provides for website tracking.